# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'llama_index.langchain_helpers.chatgpt'

Tags: python, python-3.x, openai-api, chatgpt-api, llama-index

I'd like to use `ChatGPTLLMPredictor` from `llama_index.langchain_helpers.chatgpt`, but I got an error below on M1 Macbook Air.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'llama_index.langchain_helpers.chatgpt'
```

My code looks like this and line 3 is the problem.

```py
import csv
from llama_index import GPTSimpleVectorIndex, SimpleWebPageReader
from llama_index.langchain_helpers.chatgpt import ChatGPTLLMPredictor

article_urls = []
with open('article-urls.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        article_urls.append(row[0])

documents = SimpleWebPageReader().load_data(article_urls)
index = GPTSimpleVectorIndex(documents=documents, llm_predictor=ChatGPTLLMPredictor()
)
index.save_to_disk('index.json')
```

- Python v3.10.10
- requirements.txt

```
aiohttp==3.8.4
aiosignal==1.3.1
async-timeout==4.0.2
attrs==23.1.0
cachetools==5.3.0
certifi==2022.12.7
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
dataclasses-json==0.5.7
frozenlist==1.3.3
gptcache==0.1.14
idna==3.4
langchain==0.0.142
llama-index==0.5.16
marshmallow==3.19.0
marshmallow-enum==1.5.1
multidict==6.0.4
mypy-extensions==1.0.0
numexpr==2.8.4
numpy==1.24.2
openai==0.27.4
openapi-schema-pydantic==1.2.4
packaging==23.1
pandas==2.0.0
pydantic==1.10.7
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2023.3
PyYAML==6.0
regex==2023.3.23
requests==2.28.2
six==1.16.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.47
tenacity==8.2.2
tiktoken==0.3.3
tqdm==4.65.0
typing-inspect==0.8.0
typing_extensions==4.5.0
tzdata==2023.3
urllib3==1.26.15
yarl==1.8.2
```

Thanks.

Comment: According to https://github.com/jerryjliu/llama_index/blob/main/gpt_index/llm_predictor/chatgpt.py, you should do ```from llama_index.llm_predictor.chatgpt import ChatGPTLLMPredictor```   though I am a bit confused as they're changing names

Comment: According to https://gpt-index.readthedocs.io/en/latest/development/changelog.html#breaking-deprecated-api-changes this ChatGPTLLMPredictor is deprecated. Use LLMpredictor as recommended

Answer (score 0):

in my case I was running the code in an outdated version of Jupyter, running the following commands fix it for me:

```
pip3 install --upgrade jupyter-console
pip3 install --upgrade jupyter
```